# Pong Game. How to play an audio when ball hits either paddle?

Tags: java

```
package ponggame;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.util.Random;

//This is the ball class

public class Ball implements Runnable {

    // Gloabal variables
    int x, y, xDirection, yDirection;

    // Score
    int p1Score, p2Score;

    Paddle p1 = new Paddle(15, 140, 1);
    Paddle p2 = new Paddle(370, 140, 2);

    Rectangle ball;

    public Ball(int x, int y) {
        p1Score = p2Score = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        // Set ball moving randomly
        Random r = new Random();
        int rDir = r.nextInt(1);
        if (rDir == 0)
            rDir--;
        setXDirection(rDir);
        int yrDir = r.nextInt(1);
        if (yrDir == 0)
            yrDir--;
        setYDirection(yrDir);
        // Create 'ball'
        ball = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 7, 7);
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xdir) {
        xDirection = xdir;
    }

    public void setYDirection(int ydir) {
        yDirection = ydir;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
    }

    // when it hits either paddle
    public void collision() {
        if (ball.intersects(p1.paddle))
            setXDirection(+1);// taught it was somewhere here to add audio

        if (ball.intersects(p2.paddle))
            setXDirection(-1);
    }

    public void move() {
        collision();
        ball.x += xDirection;
        ball.y += yDirection;
        // Bounce the ball when edge is detected
        if (ball.x <= 0) {
            setXDirection(+1);
            p2Score++;
        }
        if (ball.x >= 385) {
            setXDirection(-1);
            p1Score++;
        }
        if (ball.y <= 15)
            setYDirection(+1);
        if (ball.y >= 285)
            setYDirection(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                move();
            Thread.sleep(7);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

This is the paddle class:

```
package ponggame;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Paddle implements Runnable {

    int x, y, yDirection, id;

    Rectangle paddle;

    public Paddle(int x, int y, int id){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
        paddle = new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 50);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch(id){
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid ID in Paddle constructor");
                break;
            case 1:
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W){
                    setYDirection(-1);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S){
                    setYDirection(1);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP){
                    setYDirection(-1);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN){
                    setYDirection(+1);
                }
                break;            
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        switch(id){
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid ID in Paddle constructor");
                break;
            case 1:
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_W){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_S){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
                break;            
        }
    }

    public void setYDirection(int ydir){
        yDirection = ydir;
    }

    public void move(){
        paddle.y += yDirection;
        if(paddle.y <= 15)
            paddle.y = 15;
        if(paddle.y >= 250)
            paddle.y = 250;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        switch(id){
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid ID in Paddle constructor");
                break;
            case 1:
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true){
                move();
                Thread.sleep(8);
            } `enter code here`enter code here`
        }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
    }

}
```

This is the sound class I made:

```
package ponggame;

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class Sound {

    public static final Sound bgMusic = new Sound("/pong.wav");
    public static final Sound hitPaddle = new Sound("/bounce.wav");

    private AudioClip clip;

    public Sound(String fileName) {
        try {
            // gets the sound file that is passed in the constructor
            clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(fileName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // plays the music, obviously
    public void play() {
        try {
            new Thread() { //multi-tasking stuff
                public void run(){
                    //clip.play();
                    clip.loop();

                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //plays the audio in a loop
    public void loop(){
        play();
    }

}
```

The Main Class

```
package ponggame;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Image;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Main extends JFrame {

    // Double buffering
    Image dbImage;
    Graphics dbg;

    // sound relative
    private Sound sound;

    // Ball objects
    static Ball b = new Ball(193, 143);

    // Variables for screen size
    int GWIDTH = 400, GHEIGHT = 300;
    // Dimension of GWIDTH*GHEIGHT
    Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);

    // Create constructor to spawn window
    public Main() {
        this.setTitle("Pong Game - RC");
        this.setSize(screenSize);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.addKeyListener(new AL());

        sound.bgMusic.play();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        // Create and start threads
        Thread ball = new Thread(b);
        ball.start();
        Thread p1 = new Thread(b.p1);
        Thread p2 = new Thread(b.p2);
        p1.start();
        p2.start();

    }

    // handles all the music stuff
    public static void music() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        b.draw(g);
        b.p1.draw(g);
        b.p2.d(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("" + b.p1Score, 15, 50);
        g.drawString("" + b.p2Score, 370, 50);

        repaint();
    }

    // //////EVENT LISTENER CLASS/////////
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            b.p1.keyPressed(e);
            b.p2.keyPressed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            b.p1.keyReleased(e);
            b.p2.keyReleased(e);
        }
    }

}
// /////END EVENT LISTENER CLASS/////
```

Comment: Please cut down the amount of code in your question - try having a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: More than one clip can be played at the same time. You can just clip.play the bounce clip when the ball bounces. The audio system should mix them together.

Answer (score 0):

try this link:

http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound

i couldn't test it, but it looks ok.

you have to insert `AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);` in your check collision method